# How to relate 2 channels / parent relationship fields HELP

Tags: relationships, related-entries, reverse-related-entries

can someone help me get my head around a relationship field / parent? I have 2 channels. Clinic and People. The people channel has a relationship field to the clinic they work at.
When I am displaying the clinic channel I want to display the people that work there. This is not working:

Channel: Clinic Field: Title

Channel: People Field: {member_clinic} relationship field to Clinic

```
{ exp:channel:entries channel="clinic" limit="1" dynamic="yes"}
Clinic Name: { title }
People at this clinic: {parents channel="people" field="member_clinic"}
                                <div class="show">
                                        <strong>{parents:title}</strong>
                                        <div class="what">{parents:member_lastname}</div>
                                        <div class="when">{parents:member_firstname}</div>
                                </div>
                        {/parents}{ /exp:channel:entries }
```

Answer (score 1):

All you should need is this. Assuming "parents" is the name of the relationship field in the Clinic channel.
ref https://docs.expressionengine.com/latest/fieldtypes/relationships.html#accessing-children

```
{parents}
<div class="show">
<strong>{parents:title}</strong>
<div class="what">{parents:member_lastname}</div>
<div class="when">{parents:member_firstname}</div>
</div>
{/parents}
```

Comment: the related field is actually in the people channel not the clinic channel.  After more investigation I think my problem is actually with Zoo Visitor.  This add on does not know how to handle relationship fields and my people channel uses zoo visitor